# How to determine active storage association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have one upload form for all models using active storage attachment(s).  Functionality in this form can change depending on if the uploader is a has_one_attached or has_many_attached.  Is there a rails way to determine which association type a given model has?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflect_on_all_associations:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations

```
Account.reflect_on_all_associations   # returns an array of all associations
Account.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)  # returns an array of all has_many associations
```

I've not tried it but I'm assuming:

```
Model.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one_attached)
```

Will contain a record if the model :has_one_attached, and be empty if it doesn't.

Comment: reflect_on_all_associations does not include attachments.  However, rails has two other methods "reflect_on_all_attachments", and "reflect_on_attachment".  They both return a ActiveStorage::Reflection object....from which I am unsure how to determine if that reflection is a has_one or a has_many.

Comment: I could do something like Document.reflect_on_attachment(:attachments).name.ends_in?('s').  But, that seems awfully brittle.

Comment: It would be pretty ugly but you could check if the association returned is singular or plural

Comment: FWIW I tried `Model.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one_attached)` and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this approach, but it works.  All my models have only one attachment association.  If a model had more than one attachment association, this would break.  I'll continue to fine tune this.

```
def can_have_many_attachments?
  uploader_name.present? &&
    uploader_name.ends_with?('s')
end

def uploader_name
  self.class.reflect_on_all_attachments.last.name.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, at least for Active Storage.

```
ModelName.reflect_on_all_associations.select { |a|
  a.class_name == 'ActiveStorage::Attachment'
}
```

And if you want just the attribute names:

```
ModelName.reflect_on_all_associations.select { |a|
  a.class_name == 'ActiveStorage::Attachment'
}.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following code determines if the attachment named manuscript on the Publication model is a has-many attachment

```
(Publication.reflect_on_attachment :manuscript).
    instance_of? ActiveStorage::Reflection::HasManyAttachedReflection
```

(note this is all a single statement continued on a second line)

Alternatively, you can do

```
(Publication.reflect_on_attachment :manuscript).macro == :has_many_attached
```

Replace many with one to test if it's a HasOneAttached.